# Action fired on multiple events

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

In CKEditor 4 I want to fire some action on `key` and `paste` events. I've got working code for single event:

```
 $('#some_id').ckeditor({
     some: config
 }).ckeditor().editor.on('key', function(evt) {
    //some action here
});
```

And I don't want to repeat all code for next event. I've searched [ckeditor docs](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_editor.html#method-on) - and it says that `on` method takes only string, so give it an array of events isn't possible. I've tried pass multiple events as string `key, paste` - it wasn't best idea. Another way could be made an array of events and iterate it with code above - this solution seems to be not ideal, but the best I can figure out for now. Have You any better ideas for this problem?

Comment: Why not just store a reference to the `.editor` and then iterate?

Comment: It still concept with array of events and iteration. Of course if this idea will be the best any unnecessary code will be removed from loop. I'm wondering if better option exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since nobody have any idea in this matter, I finished with best solution I could figure out on this moment: provide array of events and iterate it. I paste here my solution for others facing same dillema:

```
var editor = $('#textarea').ckeditor({
                //some:config
            }).ckeditor().editor;
var events = ['event1', 'event2'];

for (event of events) {
    editor.on(event, function(evt) {
       //Yours actions
    }
}
```